# how to extract text along with the parenthesis using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

i want to extract the number (along with the parenthesis) from the text using regular expression in java 
Ex:  (234)

Comment: describe more about how the input looks like and what you want to see out of it. Have multiple scenarios with before and after

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question, it's just "gimme teh codez." Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should match:

`\(\d+\)`

as you didn't mention any requirements so I sopposed that any count of numbers are accepted. Only numbers, too.
There must not be other symbols then digits between the digits you are trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather generic, but I'll try and give an answer anyway.

Give the following string: `This is an example (123) string (234)`

Extract: `(123)` and `(234)`

You can do that using `java.util.regex` like so:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(\\d+\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("This is an example (123) string (234)");
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1));
}
```

The code above should print:

```
Found: (123)
Found: (234)
```